# xcode quit unexpectedly while trying to set maps routing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

this is the Exception type:

```
Process:         Xcode [1409]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1.1 (5085)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 520942841
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [177]
Responsible:     Xcode [1409]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-20 22:41:27.990 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  9C747CAE-C350-EB4A-8B8B-155596B575CC


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): *** -[NSKeyValueSlowMutableSet addObject:]: value for key enabledRoutingTypes of object 0x7fd447d4d9d0 is nil
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
```

this is happening to me while i've tried to going to the project navigator and then into "Capabilities " tab scrolling to the Maps section (the switch is on) and then trying ti mark any Routing selection .
i've tried to open new project and it is happening again .

Comment: Try updating to Xcode 6.

Comment: I had the same bug with Xcode 6.1. Disabling and then re-enabling the Maps capability fixed it, as suggested by Mongi Zaidi below.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. It disappeared after I disabled the Maps capability and then enabled it again

Answer (score 1):

Please report this to Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com/

Even though it is an old version of Xcode, the bug may still exist in the current version.

Comment: It does indeed exist in the current version.

Comment: jep it does, but the fix from @Mongi Zaidi is still working :)